# Which permissions need to be assigned to a normal user to allow him to change SHARE permissions?

Tags: windows-server-2003, permissions, share

As in the subject - I am wondering, which permissions (if it is possible) do I need to assign to a regular user to modify the share permissions - e.g. to add another user with full control permissions, or to deny someone read access to the folder - on a share level.

I know that this is possible through NTFS permissions, but I am wondering whether it is also possible on share level. Any ideas how to do that?

Or perhaps only the adminstrator/creator/person who shared the folder has the access to this?
I am using win2003

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: May I ask why you are using share permissions at all? Why not just limit this with NTFS ACL's?

Comment: Let's say that it's an academic dispute;-) But let's say that the shared folder is created on FAT? Would it have more sense?

Comment: I don't think it's a permission that is needed, it is a user right that is needed. To create shared folders generally requires Administrator or equivalent user rights, but I don't know the specific user right that is needed.

Answer (score 1):

He needs to be at least in the Power Users group.